# How can I round up decimal values in C++?

Tags: c++, math, rounding

If I have, for example, the number 9.83333 and I want to round it to 9.84 or 9.9. How can I do this?

Comment: @ruohola That question seems to address older C++ versions and rounding to the nearest integer, rather than what this question seems to be abound (rounding to nearest tenths or hundredths).

Comment: To round; https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round

Comment: Note that floating point are usually **NOT** decimal values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken for more information.

Comment: @AProgrammer: the OP means fractional values.

Comment: @templatetypedef: what ??? What does "older C++ versions" have to do with this ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, are you sure?  I've seen far too many people wondering why adding 0.9 to 0.1 is not equal to 1.0 not to try to avoid that second question.

Comment: @AProgrammer: more than sure. Read the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There was an earlier, but since deleted, comment suggesting a question this might have been a duplicate of. That question was about an equivalent to std::round for C++98.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s a function called `std::round` in the `<cmath>` header file that rounds a real number to the nearest integer. You can use that to round to the nearest tenth by computing `std::round(10 * x) / 10.0`, or to the nearest hundredth by calling `std::round(100 * x) / 100.0`. (Do you see why that works?)

You seem to be more interested in rounding up rather than rounding to the nearest value, which you can do by using the `std::ceil` function rather than `std::round`. However, the same basic techniques above still work for this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did you choose to use floating point literals for the division which is done in a floating point type anyway after arithmetic conversions, but an integer literal for the multiplication?

Comment: No reason. :-) I figure that marking the division as a floating point operation might make it clearer to readers that indeed the result is floating-point.

Comment: For the pedantic, the first scaling like `10 * x` can incur a rounding such that `round()` provides the wrong answer.  This happens in select half way cases near x.x5.  Also `10 * x` may overflow - easy enough to pre-test as all large `double` are whole numbers and need no fractional decimal rounding.